# Checkbox OnClick/ItemCommand in Repeater or DataList

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, datalist

I need to do some server side logic on a row in my repeater when a CheckBox is clicked inside the repeater control.

**Anyone know how to go about this?**

The way I see it you cant fire item command and if you use the CheckBoxes OnClick you cant get the repeater row.

Comment: Here is an answer: http://www.frankwisniewski.net/2013/01/15/how-to-make-a-checkbox-fire-the-itemcommand-event-of-a-repeater/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a quick mock-up of how I have done similar in the past.

```
    <asp:Repeater id="repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repeater1_OnItemDataBound" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chk" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="Check_Changed" AutoPostBack="true" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

codebehind:

```
    public class Model {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Checkboxes : System.Web.UI.Page {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            if(!IsPostBack ) {
                repeater1.DataSource = new List<Model> { 
                               new Model { Id = 1, Name = "a" }, 
                               new Model { Id = 2, Name = "b" }, 
                               new Model { Id = 3, Name = "c" } };
                repeater1.DataBind();
            }
        }

        protected void repeater1_OnItemDataBound(Object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) {
                var item = e.Item.DataItem as Model;
                if (item != null) {
                    var chk = e.Item.FindControl("chk") as CheckBox;
                    if (chk != null) {
                        chk.Text = item.Name;
                        chk.InputAttributes.Add("value", item.Id.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        protected void Check_Changed(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
            var id = ((CheckBox) sender).InputAttributes["value"];
            //you now have access to the item id and can manipulate at will.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks this should work. Wish there was a less round about way... +1

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do with the data. If it is a simple database flag update for a single row, an AJAX callback hooked up through JQuery would be a better and cleaner approach. In fact, it is probably a cleaner approach, no matter what you are doing with the data. It would allow users to change multiple checkboxes without postbacks.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing.  Thanks for the mockup though.  It clearly illustrated how overly complicated it was and steered me in the JQuery direction. =D

Answer (score 2):

Try this codebehind:

```
 protected void Checked_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var item = ((CheckBox)sender).Parent as RepeaterItem;
// now you have the repeater row. You can travers further up the controls if you use Parent.Parent...

        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use the OnClick event to loop through each item in the repeater, and check the value of each checkbox, (IsChecked == true).

Just make sure that you are not calling a "DataBind()" on the repeater, otherwise that might cause issues.

Comment: So I will have to keep a record of the current state if I want OnChange functionality?  Is there not another way?

Comment: The current state is recorded in the properties of each checkbox, so you shouldn't have to do anything extra besides just loop through each checkbox.