# Adding or attaching an OnItemCommand Event handler to ASP.NET CheckBox

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, repeater

I wonder if it is possible to add or attach or extend the asp.net checkbox in a way to add OnCommand , CommandName, CommandArgument functionality.

In brief I want to add to a asp. net CheckBox the OnCommand functionality like Button or LinkButton has.

I want to place a check box in a Repeater ItemTemplate and want to handle on checkbox clicks in OnItemCommand handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem using a simple trick. I created a web user control using a checkbox and invisible link button.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbSelector" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnHiddenCheckBox" runat="server" Visible="false" CommandName="Select"></asp:LinkButton>
```

in the code behind i added some event handlers ...

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     cbSelector.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(cbSelector_CheckedChanged);
  }

  void cbSelector_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      btnHiddenCheckBox.CommandName = "Select";
      btnHiddenCheckBox.CommandArgument = Convert.ToString(cbSelector.Checked);
      ((IPostBackEventHandler)btnHiddenCheckBox).RaisePostBackEvent(null);
  }
```

and programmatically raised a Click event with parameters and it works.

Answer (score 0):

The same could be achieved using `OnCheckChanged` event.

You can find out what the `RepeaterItem` is to be able to access controls in the same `RepeaterItem`

---

ALternatively, see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566979/checkbox-onclick-itemcommand-in-repeater-or-datalist) for a solution on how to use `OnItemCommand` for `CheckBox`:

[Checkbox OnClick/ItemCommand in Repeater or DataList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566979/checkbox-onclick-itemcommand-in-repeater-or-datalist)

Comment: Yes. I know the OnCheckChanged event but I want to place all in the OnItemCommand event handler of the Repeater.

Comment: Updated my answer with a link to an existing similar question. You may find this useful

Answer (score 0):

Patrik I am going to suggest you something completely different, use `JQuery` and get this done via Ajax so to give the users way smoother experience.

there is a nice article with a step by step here: [ASP.Net CheckBox and JQuery](http://elegantcode.com/2009/02/02/aspnet-checkbox-and-jquery/)

everything is better than a `CheckBox` or a `Button` with `AutoPostBack` set to true nowadays in year 2011, 2012 soon ;-)

Comment: Thank you. Your solution is OK but in my situation I will stick to the server side. I must do something in the OnItemCommand of the repeater that is complex.