# How to trigger Item_Command event for Checkbox in Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, repeater

I am having a repeater which contains check-boxes,I want to fire the item_command event whenever a check-box on the repeater is checked.
But since item_Command event wont fire for check-box.
Googled it and heard that Bubble Event wont trigger for check box,is there some other way i can achieve this?

Thank You

Askar

Comment: have a look at this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566979/checkbox-onclick-itemcommand-in-repeater-or-datalist

Comment: Can you add code for better answer?

Comment: Do you need to call up a server side method whenever check-box is checked/un-checked? Is this what your requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Upvote MarkAnswer
Finally did it...
declared item_created event for the repeater and added the following code,

```
  protected void RptrIncdntType_ItemCreated(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
  {
    RepeaterItem item = (RepeaterItem)e.Item;
    if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        CheckBox chkbxSafety = item.FindControl("chkbxSafety") as CheckBox;
        chkbxSafety.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(CheckBox2_CheckedChanged);
    }
  }

 private void CheckBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
 {
   CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)sender;
 }
```