# fetching data in repeater's ItemCommand event in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, repeater, itemcommand

(in asp.net) I have repeater which contains different controls like checkbox, textarea, radiobutton and button(Submit). When i click on submit button, ItemCommand event is fired and i want to get data from these controls there. How can i do this? Please help me with this code.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read the guides found in https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking to get a better insight on how to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please refer this  one of the StackOverFlow questions
[Checkbox OnClick/ItemCommand in Repeater or DataList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3566979/checkbox-onclick-itemcommand-in-repeater-or-datalist)

[linkbutton on repeater - how to retrieve a field value on a selected row?](https://forums.asp.net/t/1478361.aspx?linkbutton%20on%20repeater%20how%20to%20retrieve%20a%20field%20value%20on%20a%20selected%20row%20)

Comment: Thanks @Frost_Mourne got the code logic i needed through this link.